# Substitution not being applied when pattern and configuration appear to match

Tags: kframework

I have a rule of the form

```
rule <k> (try S1 catch(Param) S2 => S1 ~> foo) ~> K </k>
     <stack> .List => ListItem((bar)) ... </stack>
```

where `stack` is a list type cell in my configuration that is a sibling of the `k` cell and `foo` is a function.

When my program gets stuck, the `k` cell outputs `<k> try { baz } catch(p) { buz } </k>` and the `stack` cell `<stack> .List </stack>`. It seems to me that these two do match and that the substitution defined in the rule should apply, however `krun` gets stuck here. The outputted configuration, syntax, and types appear to match so I'm wondering if there are any other reasons why a substitution would not be applied.

For context this is a modification of the `simple-typed-static` language in the tutorial; I've removed parts of the rule and output for clarity though those all match as well. I'm compiling this using the java backend.

Edit: I've added the syntax declarations below

```
syntax Stmt ::= "try" Block "catch" "(" Param ")" Block
syntax Block ::= "{" Stmts "}"
syntax Param ::= Type Id
```

with the configuration having, in addition to the standard `k` cell and a few other (I think) irrelevant cells,

```
<stack multiplicity="?"> .List </stack>
```

and the function `foo` having the form of

```
syntax KItem ::= "foo"
rule <k> foo => . ... </k>
     <stack> ListItem(_) => .List ... </stack>
```

Comment: We really need to see the relevant syntax productions in order to tell you more.

Comment: Apologies, I've added some additional syntax declarations while still trying to keep the example minimal.

Comment: Is that the only production of sort Param?

Comment: Yes, there is a `Params` which is a list of `Param` sorts however I don't think that should be an issue

Answer (score 0):

p is not of sort Param, which is why this rule is not applying. I'm not sure how your term came to be ill-typed, though. K's java backend is quite old and has a number of design flaws that can lead to broken type safety while rewriting. It's impossible to tell the cause without more information though. I would recommend stepping through the program by executing it up to various depths with krun --depth and try to determine how you came to have a term of sort Id where a term of sort Param is expected, when Id is not a subsort of Param.

Comment: Ah this is my bad, I think I was unclear when I wrote my question, I just shortened the param to `p` in my `k` cell, the actual code there is `int e` which does match a `Param`

Comment: I really need to see the entire relevant part of the example then. I would recommend trying to make a small, self contained definition that reproduces the issue.

Comment: In the process of trying to create a minimal example I seem to have "fixed" the issue by changing the pattern from `rule <k> (try S1 catch(Param) S2 => S1 ~> foo) ~> K </k>` to `rule <k> (try {S} catch(Param) S2 => {S} ~> foo) ~> K </k>` and adding a case for the empty block. I have no idea if this actually resolved the underlying issue or why this should have worked but it appears to have. While unsatisfying I think I'll work from here. Thank you very much for all of your patience and help!